# Parse json document to extract node's value without knowing root property name in C#( .net core)

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Is there a better way to parse json document and extract property value of a particular node in C#(.net core), without knowing root property's name? Given: - **root** of json document will have only *one property* but *property name is unknown*.
Would prefer to have a solution without using NewtonSoft library but instead System.Text.JSon

Sample json document below:

```
{
  "rootPropertyName": {
    "someProperty1": "TCC",
    "someProperty2": "128-1600-8routeextent",
    "eventType": "RouteUpdated",
     ---leaving other properties for sake of brevity---
  }
}
```

As seen above, I would like to parse above json document to extract a particular node's value say "eventType" (*this property name is known to me*) but I don't know the root property name.

Current implementation:

```
using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonContent);
{               
 JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;
 string rootPropertyName = root.EnumerateObject().First().Name;
 var eventType = root.GetProperty(rootPropertyName).GetProperty("eventType").GetString();
 var payload = root.GetProperty(rootPropertyName).ToString();
 return (eventType, payload);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);

Dictionary<string,string> propertiesDict = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>
(doc.RootElement.EnumerateObject().First().Value.ToString());

string someProperty2 = propertiesDict["someProperty2"];
```

or you can deserialize to a c# object

```
Properties properties = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Properties>(
doc.RootElement.EnumerateObject().First().Value.ToString());

string someProperty2 = properties.someProperty2;
```

class

```
class Properties
{
    public string someProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string someProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string eventType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, YourClass>`. There would be a single key `rootPropertyName` and the value would be the whole `{ "someProperty1":...` object

```cs
class YourClass
{
    public string someProperty1;
    public string someProperty2;
    public string eventType;
}
```

```cs
var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, YourClass>>(jsonContent);
return (dict.Values.First.eventType, dict.Keys.First);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regex

```
(?:\"your-key\"\s*\:\s*)((\[((?<g1>[^\[\]]+|(?1))*)\])|({((?<g2>[^{}]+|(?1))*)})|(\".*\"))
```

In c# it looks like this

```cs
public static string GetValue(string json, string key, string json)
{
    var pattern = $"(?:\"{key}\"\\s*\\:\\s*)((\\[((?<g1>[^\\[\\]]+|(?1))*)\\])|({{((?<g2>[^{{}}]+|(?1))*)}})|(\".*\"))";
    var regex = new PCRE.PcreRegex(pattern);

    return regex.Match(json).Value;
}
```

**Note** : I use the [Pcre.Net](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net) nugget package because .net's regex doesn't support some features.